# Paperclip don't show the image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

well i have this problem

i have this in my model service

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

    has_attached_file :images, :styles => {:md => "300x300>", :large => "500x500>" , :xl => "700x700#"}, :default_url => "/app/assets/images/thumb/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :images, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/   

end
```

and this in my view Services#index

```
    <div>
      <%= image_tag service.images(:md)%>
    </div>
```

but there's a problem in my view the image set when i put :large or :xl but when i put :md the images don't shows. i don't know what's happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `:large`and `:xl` are working when you replace it with `:md` in your index view, then I would guess that there's simply no version for `:md` available to show. Have you added `:md` to the model, after you actually already uploaded an image? I would delete the image and try that again.